# Date format 'ww' not working in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, date-formatting

I am trying to display a week number using the 'ww' date formater in Angularjs.

my code looks like this

```
    //in my directive controller
    $scope.today = new Date();  


    //in my templateUrl
    <span id="weeknumber">Week: {{today| date:'ww'}}</span>
```

This doesnt seem to work for me, i can get the formatter to work for all format types except 'ww' & 'w'.

My expected output is: **Week: 23** but instead i get **Week: 'ww'**

Am I missing something here or is this an issue with Angularjs itself?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are beneath Version 1.3 of Angular. 'ww' or 'w' is only working with the newest Version of Angular.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, the angular docs are great in some ways but really lacking in others. Versioning was an angle I hadn't looked at, thanks again.

Comment: A thing I was stumbling across some times also ;-). I've forgotten to look at the version of the docs and wondering why the feature is not there where I've found it a month before...